# error:expected ':', ',' or')' before '.' token

Tags: c

I get the error `error:expected ':', ',' or')' before '.' token` in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

void filecopy(FILE*,FILE*);

int main()
{
    FILE*fpin,*fpout;

    fpin = fopen("file_a.dat", "r");//
    fpout = fopen("file_b.dat", "w");
    filecopy(fpin, fpout);
    fclose ( fpin );
    fclose  ( fpout );

}

void filecopy(FILE*fpin.FILE*fpout)//(FILE*fpin,FILE*fpout)
{
    char ch;

    ch = getc (fpin);

    while (!feof(fpin));//delete the ';'
    {
        putc (ch,fpout);
        ch = getc (fpin);
    }
}
```

PS:Again,I'm sorry for my hasty and meaningless question.It was blame for my careless coding habit ,and don't think it over.I'll pay attention to asking question on stackoverflow.But I stil want to say thanks to the people who had answered and commented.

Comment: Paste code not image.

Comment: `,` instead of `.`.

Comment: The `while`-loop on line 25 is followed by semi-colon, which is not what you want. Also you should make `main()` return void or return a value :)

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) And take a closer look to line 19 ...

Comment: Why are you down voting? It's clearly not off-topic and it's pretty clear what's being asked.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my mistake.I'll learn  how to paste code and correct it next time

Comment: @刘歆佳 if your problem is solved, you can accept the answer that helped you so that the question appears as resolved.

Comment: @pzaenger: not as used here. It is correct.

Comment: @fpg1503,I originally thought it's a symbol of my collection.Sorry.

Comment: @DavidBowling my bad, auto correct changed it. thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Two mistakes :***

***1.*** Replace line :

```
while (!feof(fpin));
```

with :

```
while (!feof(fpin))       //without semicolon (;)
```

***2.*** Replace line :

```
void filecopy(FILE *fpin.FILE *fpout);
```

with :

```
void filecopy(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerelly.

Comment: @刘歆佳 I am glad that I helped.

Comment: `void filecopy(FILE *fpin, FILE *fpout);` ← semicolon should be removed

Comment: Why?It's a declaration that shold be end up with semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

In line 19 you have separated function arguments with dot instead of comma.